# Sum of Vertices in Induced Graph - Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming

This is a homework question so I'll be glad to get a hint.

I have a graph G, where each vertex v has a weight w(v).

S(G) is the sum of weights of the all the vertexes in the graph.

I need to find an algorithm that determines if there is a group of vertexes A, when G[A] (G's graph induced by A) is a tree, that conducts S(G[A])=S(G[V\A]).

I know that i should go over all vertexes, sum their weights, and then try to find a tree that reaches half of that sum, but i'm not sure how exactly. I'm pretty sure it involves dynamic programming.

Thank you very much,

Yaron.

Comment: what about required complexity?

Comment: @Herokiller there is none. Although, i think it's dynamic programming so i'm trying to think about a complexity of o(N^2) or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a dynamic programming problem, it is a search problem, the key being that you are trying to find a tree.

If you think about it, you already know an algorithm or two that will will tell you the minimum spanning tree. By the same logic, you can make a maximum spanning tree. For example, if you find the maximum spanning tree and the sum of its weights is less than 50% (or whatever the target value is), then you know the problem is impossible.

So, following this logic, you can go along as though you were making a spanning tree and reject any path that goes over the target amount. This strategy is known as "branch and bound". Let's imagine how we could do this with Kruskal's algorithm:

(1) you will have a set of trees; start with each vertex as a separate "tree"

(2) maintain a queue of edges you have not used yet, sorted from least to greatest

(3) maintain a stack of edges that you have used

(4) look for an edge that (a) connects two different trees, and (b) the sum of the two trees is less than (or equal to the target value, ie a solution)

(4a) if no such edge exists, then pop a value from the stack (remove the edge and seperate the trees) and try the next value in the queue

(4b) if such an edge does exist, then add the edge (combine two of the trees), push it onto the stack and go back to step 4

Obviously there are different ways to do the same process. For example, you could use a variant of Prim's algorithm as well.